# Unit Testing in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing

I am fairly new to unit testing. I am in school, and currently taking junior projects. We have a web application to write. We are going to use C# and asp.net. We are currently doing all the requirements, architecture, and i am responsible for the Quality Assurance and picking the right framework. We have a ton of paperwork to complete and i am trying to get my QA plan finished.

I am not sure what to use for unit testing. Although, we will be using asp.net i dont think we have the need to use MVC at this point. For simplicity sake should we just use visual studio built in functionality to  Generate an ASP.NET unit test? Or, should i look into using Nunit? or something like it?

Keep in mind this is just a school project. Our team of 4 will all have to perform the unit tests and most of us dont have much experience in it.

What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> For simplicity sake should we just use visual studio built in
>   functionality to Generate an ASP.NET unit test?

No, that's completely useless. Well, you could use it for your school project or something but don't fool yourself that you are doing unit testing.

> Or, should i look into using Nunit? or something like it?

Yeah, definitely. But in order to successfully be able to unit test your ASP.NET application, it needs to be designed so that the different layers are weakly coupled between them and could be reused in isolation. This is easily achieved by using abstractions (interfaces and abstract classes) instead of working with concrete implementations. Also remember that any code that is dependent on an HttpContext cannot be easily unit tested in isolation. The best way is to work with the abstractions provided by ASP.NET like HttpContextBase, HttpRequestBase, HttpResponseBase, ... which can easily be mocked in a unit test.

Comment: Darin, you can still have weak coupling with concrete classes though, no?  In other words, if you business layer consumes the classes of your data layer, your data layer can still be tested in an isolated manner from the bl.

Comment: @Shark, no, your business layer is now strongly coupled to your data access layer making it impossible to unit test in isolation. Yeah, you can unit test your data layer which doesn't depend on any other layer (other than the database). So to answer your question `you can still have weak coupling with concrete classes though, no`, the answer is `no, you cannot have weak coupling with concrete classes`.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying now.  +1 on your answer by the way.  So is this how you design a majority of your n-tiered solutions?  Never any concrete classes spanning across a layer, just interfaces and abstract classes?

Comment: @Shark, that's exactly how I am designing my applications. I first define the contract of what I am trying to achieve (as an interface or abstract class) and then I provide some implementation.

Comment: Ok, cool.  Thanks for the lesson and verification.  I like that, I'm going to take that onboard.

Comment: I know what you mean. I did take a design patterns class. I do think we could use some of that strategy in our project.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to write unit tests, you need to decouple your logic from your presentation. MVC is great at that, which makes it much more unit testable than webforms. It's not impossible to test webforms, just harder.

Ultimately, though, you just need to keep [SOLID](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29&ei=LaUtT8znB8Ps0gHK8uTYCg&usg=AFQjCNHMwHjI1CzjM0208uMB6OSA3S4jug) principles in mind and make sure that you liberally use interfaces throughout your project so that you can mock them.

NUnit versus MSTest isn't really an issue. There's more or less feature parity between the two, and the upside of MStest is that it's all built right into Visual Studio. Go with whatever you want.

I'd recommend reading the book *[The Art of Unit Testing](http://artofunittesting.com/)*, as well.

Depending on the size and scope of your project, it may be worth looking into using an inversion of control framework such as [Ninject](http://ninject.org/) to tie all your dependencies together.

Comment: I did take a design patterns class. I do think that we could possibly use some type of pattern. The project is just a online web app that creates a automated job application for a retail chain. Im still confused on what to use. If i go  with asp.MVC should i go with the built in VS feature?

Comment: @icelated I'm not sure what you mean by "built in VS feature". Do you mean the MVC project template? If so, then yes. MVC is more testable and flexible than webforms, but requires a bit more work from the developer.

Comment: In VS there is a test tab. If you click that it gives you new test Dialog pops up and you have a few selections: Basic unit test. Generic test, load test, unit test, etc..

Answer (score 0):

Agree with both. Definitely and issue if your stuff is too tightly coupled (integrated and relying on each other).  Break the coupling into non user interface requirements that you can send all the tests through, and I definitely use NUnit with C#, but our dev work is with WPF.  All the data handling and static functions can all be tested to confirm limits, nulls, missing / invalid parameters, expected results back vs what REALLY gets returned.  Not done well could put a hurt on your site quickly otherwise.

Comment: I think i will have a second look at using MVC instead. I took a design patterns class and i think we could incorporate this. I will look into NUnit.